# How to get the attachment from an http post to Domino document?

Tags: ajax, file-upload, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I need to use a Domino page with ajax file upload plugin to upload multiple files. Every plugin has a url parameter to config for posting the data/files in the form to server.

I set the url with "myform?createdocument" and I made a Notes form named "myform". My question is what should I do to this form so that I can save the document with the files attached as $FILE items? Thank you.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about the plugin? eg what yopu mean by "Every plugin has a url parameter to config " ? ta

Comment: Hi, ta. Thank you for your response. The plugin is http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php

Answer (score 1):

That's tricky - lets say you have your document showing as a web page ..

1) You're viewing your web page = the edit session on the document. So you have ability to save other parts of it (title etc) ?

2) you upload an attachment to that document via ajax (so doc is now changed)

3) the backend document is now a different 'sequence' to the one being edited at the front end. I suspect Domino will notice this and you'll get a Save conflict when you save the actual document.

I think you'll need to something like ..

- Add a new form (Notes design element Form I mean) just for the attachment(s) which has a web file upload on it. Call is say "Attachment". This tells the Notes server that it should handle a file upload for that type of form.
- Your URL for the upload becomes the Attachments form eg Attachment?CreateDocument&seq=1
- Save the attachments as separate documents with a link (eg a key or the UNID) to the 'parent' document.
- When you save the parent doc, using a web query save agent, have it look for any attachments waiting to be added - maybe look up in a view by the aforesaid key.
- If any found, add them to the parent doc with embedobject and then delete the attachments docs to clean up.

Either that or view the attachments as a separate document and list them on the parent doc via a lookup to a view that contains them. There's a lot to be said for that approach, as it gives you more opportunoty to adminster them separately, although one disadvantage would be if you're using a FT search, the attachments aren't actually on the parent doc so you have to be careful about whether people would expect to find a document by searching throughthe attachments.

Obviously I haven't tried this but I thnk that's what will work.